# What's upgraded exactly when you upgrade a Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

As explained in the article [Controlling the fabric version that runs on your Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade), you can choose which version of Service Fabric you want Azure to create for you.
The ServiceFabric nuget package seem to have the same version numbers as the clusters, but older versions of the packages work just fine with newer versions of the cluster.

Now, the [release notes for version 5.4.145](https://servicefabricsdkstorage.blob.core.windows.net/public-release-notes/Microsoft%20Azure%20Service%20Fabric%20Release%20Notes%20-%20SDK%202.4.145%20-%20Runtime%205.4.145.docx) state a list of improvements, and mentions that some older versions won't be supported anymore.

What I'm failing to understand is -
Will I get the list of improvements just by upgrading my cluster, or do I also have to upgrade my nuget packages?
Similarly, does it mean I have to upgrade my nuget packages soon, otherwise I'm at risk of running deprecated code?

Would also be nice to get some clarification of what exactly is upgraded when I upgrade a cluster, what's upgraded when I upgrade my packages, and how the two upgrades relate to each other.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the Runtime and the SDK. When the cluster is upgraded, it gets a new runtime. Any improvements in that runtime will be available to existing services running in the cluster.

Upgrading the SDK (or the Nuget packages) will result in new functionality to become available to applications (services/actors) built on top of the cluster runtime.

I'd recommend updating Nuget packages soon after upgrading the cluster to keep them in sync.

Comment: Would I be right in saying that the SDK is essentially the client code for the runtime services running on the cluster?

Comment: The word 'services' is a bit confusing in this explanation. The runtime is like the CLR and the SDK like the .NET framework (as an analogy).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still not sure I understand what "runtime" consists of in this context.

Comment: Also, if you take a look at an [arbitrary release announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/06/13/release-of-service-fabric-sdk-2-1-150-and-runtime-5-1-150/), the SDK has versions of the type 2.*.***, while the runtime has versions of the type 5.*.***. The nuget package Microsoft.ServiceFabric has versions of the form 5.*.***. Does it mean it's not a part of the SDK? Is it a part of the runtime? Does it get upgraded automatically for me with the cluster? I'm lost.

Comment: The package 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric' is part of the sdk, its version matches the runtime version it supports. The other packages are also part of the sdk, but with a version number 'runtime - 3'. (reason unknown). So, the nuget packages are all SDK packages. The Runtime is installed with the cluster.